# Angular 10 HttpClient unable to add body and header

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Using Angular 10 and HttpClient with following data:

```
const data = {
  'username': username,
  'password': password
};
const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'}

const body = JSON.stringify(data);
return this.httpClient.post(endPointURL, body,{'headers':headers})
```

On endPointURL I can see body details as null. But if I remove header like this:

```
return this.httpClient.post(endPointURL, body)
```

I can see body details correct. I need to implement body data and header. Could you please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the `headers` as -

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

// OR,
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

and pass it as `{headers: headers}`.

Also, you don't need to `JSON.stringify` the `data`.

Try something like -

```
const data = {
  'username': username,
  'password': password
};

let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

return this.httpClient.post(endPointURL, data, {headers: headers});
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps.

1. ```
       import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
   ```
2. ```
       const headers = { headers: new HttpHeaders({"Content-Type":"application/json"})}
       const body= { 'username': username, 'password': password};
   ```
3. ```
         return this.httpClient.post(endPointURL, body,headers)
   ```